# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not starting GUI on RTX 3070 graphics card

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, gui, nvidia-geforce

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on system with new RTX 3070 graphics card no GUI is displayed. The only thing on screen is flickering cursor. What could be the problem and what should I do to enable the GUI?

Comment: Edit the question and try to give some screenshots in the question.

Comment: @yaa__ its pretty hard to make screenshots without GUI. But you can also post a pucture taken from your phone

Comment: Picture is not mine but it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEwTI.png